# Overlapping form select when window is small

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following selection boxes that are working with select2 js:

```
<!-- Selections for the table -->
<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <label for="month" class="control-label">Year</label>
    <select class="form-control select2" id="year" name="year" data-placeholder="Select a year">
        <option value="2015">
            xxx
        </option>
        ...
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <label for="manager" class="control-label">Manager</label>
    <select class="form-control select2" id="manager" name="manager" data-placeholder="Select a manager" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="2">
            xxx
      </option>
      ...
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <label for="user" class="control-label">User</label>
    <select class="form-control select2" id="user" name="user" data-placeholder="Select a user" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="87">
            xxx
        </option>
        ...
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using bootstrap 3 and it is strange, when I get a smaller window, the boxes overlap :(. You can see this in the image below.
[image]

How can I have bootstrap to make the different select get below each other when there is not enough space and in a line if there is enough space horizontally?

Comment: You could try to adapt your grid, maybe try something like `col-sm-2 col-xs-12` as classes for your columns, that way they get full sized when in mobile and should float underneath each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below CSS:

```
.select2{width:100%}
```

if this not working then you can use:

```
.select2{width:100% !important}
```

Comment: I ve done that and they don't overlap but if I check this on a smartphone, they don't get below each other.

Comment: Please share a screenshot of the smartphone.